# How to enable CORS in Amazon OpenSearch / Elasticsearch via a REST API?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-opensearch

We are getting started with Amazon OpenSeach / Elasticsearch.
We have built a 7.10 cluster and need to enable CORS in it:

```
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length
http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

I did not find any configuration options for this within AWS console, so I assume that there is a way of making a change to ES 7.10 configuration via a REST API.

Is there a way to enable CORS in a fully-managed ES 7 instance?

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33337157/aws-elasticsearch-and-cors